# Oracle SQL query to select 3 characters after dot

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to extract 3 characters after dot.

Input value: ABC.1234556788
Expected Output: 123

Please advise, thanks in advance

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: I agree with Matthew: WHY THE DOWNVOTES? If there is anything wrong with the question, please say what that is, to benefit the OP and everyone else. Alas, I imagine these are some of the imbeciles this site is not immune from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of `substr` and `instr`.

```
select substr(col,instr(col,'.')+1,3) 
from tablename
where instr(col,'.') > 0
```